# Problem with making a button that changes color in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a missing word game where you have to choose correct missing word out of few.
For example.
"The Sun _____." 
A. shine
B. shines
C. shining.

After that there should be button that changes the color of missing word to green if its correct and red if its wrong.

I have tried to make if else statement but I think I'm not good enough

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("demo") = "shines") {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>1. The Sun
  <select>
    <option id="demo" value="shine">shine</option>
    <option id="demo" value="shining">shining</option>
    <option id="demo" value="shines">shines</option>
  </select>
</p><button onclick="myFunction()">Check!</button>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. Move it to the `<select>`, then use `document.getElementById('select').value`. Plus, comparisons are done using `==` or `===`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pvh4y72s/ (also, if the option text is the same as the value, you can omit the value attribute) (edit: and in my comment, `getElementById('select')` is supposed to be `getElementById('demo')`)

Comment: thanks Chris. Is it possible to make one function but many sentences? For example. 1. The Sun shines <button> 2. I play football <button>. How to make one function but buttons changes only color of one sentence? I made a function but when i click first button it changes color of first and second sentence

Comment: I updated the fiddle.

Comment: Great! It works fine. But could you tell me how to make the same thing but using input not select?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

1. Your `if` statement is making an assignment instead of equality

   This has 1 `=` sign

   ```
   if (document.getElementById("demo").value = "shines")
   ```

   Should be like this:

   ```
   if (document.getElementById("demo").value == "shines")
   ```
2. You shouldn't create multiple elements with the same id (`demo` in
   your case). I think you wanted to give the `<select/>` element the
   id and not to the `<option/>`?
3. You may want to check:

   ```
   document.getElementById("demo").value
   ```

Here is a running code that may help you keep going:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("demo").value == "shines") {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>1. The Sun
  <select id="demo">
    <option value="shine">shine</option>
    <option value="shining">shining</option>
    <option value="shines">shines</option>
  </select>
</p><button onclick="myFunction()">Check!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :)) Is it possible to make one function but many sentences? How can I make a function that changes color of only one word in one sentence even if I have 10 sentences that I have to check?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for value using `.value` on the `<select>` element, not on `<option>`, and secondly, you should compare with `===` or `==`, not with `=`

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("demo").value === "shines") {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Present Simple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>1. The Sun
    <select id="demo">
      <option value="shine">shine</option>
      <option value="shining">shining</option>
      <option value="shines">shines</option>
    </select>
  </p><button onclick="myFunction()">Check!</button>
</body>
</html>
```